# Python3: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have my data stored in json format. And by using json:load() I am reading the data.

What I am trying to do is based on argument passed , I am trying to extract specific part of Key:Value from the list and storing them into a new list for later processing.

## Code

```
selected_env='mydev2'
server_list=[{'mydev': ['192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102']}, {'mydev2': ['192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102']}]         
for item in server_list :
    host_list=[item for item in server_list[selected_env] if selected_env in server_list]

print(host_list)
```

And I am getting error as

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

**Note**: I have achieved already one way of extraction as below

```
for item in server_list:
  for element in item :
    if element == selected_env :
       host_list=item[selected_env]
```

even though its working, I thought of optimizing it and went to read some articles on list extraction and kind of stuck with above error.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your input data is necessarily a list of dictionaries, I suggest you to first convert it to a single dictionay, using a nice dict comprehension, as follows:

```
selected_env='mydev2'
server_list=[{'mydev': ['192.168.56.101', '192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.103']}, {'mydev2': ['192.168.56.104', '192.168.56.105', '192.168.56.106']}] 

server_dict = {k:v for d in server_list for k,v in d.items()}
host_list = server_dict[selected_env]

print(host_list)
```

***Note:***
*`d.items()` returns a list containing all the tuples (key,value) of the dictionary `d`.*
*So for my code, in the dict comprehension:*

1. *On 1st iteration, `d` equals `{'mydev': ['192.168.56.101', '192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.103']}` and `d.items()` equals `[('mydev',['192.168.56.101', '192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.103'])]`*
2. *On 2nd iteration, `d` equals `{'mydev2': ['192.168.56.104', '192.168.56.105', '192.168.56.106']}` and `d.items()` equals `[('mydev2',['192.168.56.104', '192.168.56.105', '192.168.56.106'])]`*

Comment: Thank you, seems I can use this solution. Would you mind adding a bit about d.item().

Comment: You're welcome. I have updated my post with additional explanations about `d.items()`

Answer (score 3):

Why use a list of dicts when a simple dict would work ???

```
servers={
   'mydev': ['192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102'], 
   'mydev2': ['192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102'],
   }

host_list = servers["mydev2"]
```

Dict lookups are O(1) and extremely optimized (dicts being used everywhere in Python internals). A list lookup is O(N).

Comment: aah! No servers is not created by me. I am extracting it from json file. So I feel your solutions not work for my case but thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing wrong is you are accessing element in list `server_list` by `selected_env` which is a string.

```
server_list[selected_env]
```

The above statement caused your error. Instead you need to check if `selected_env` is in an `item` of `server_list`.

This should work:

```
selected_env='mydev2'
server_list=[{'mydev': ['192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102']}, {'mydev2': ['192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102']}]         
for item in server_list :
    host_list = [item[selected_env] for item in server_list if selected_env in item]
host_list = list(itertools.chain(*host_list)) # To convert sub-list into flat
# assumed as import itertools included    

print(host_list)
# [['192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102', '192.168.56.102']]
```

Comment: aah! Thank you for pointing my mistake. But I need only list as output but by your answer its showing as dict so again I have to pass `host_list[selected_env]`. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about that. I misunderstood your output. Updated the snippet now.

Comment: Thank you for adding the answer. I have accepted the other answer and already upvoted your answer(feel cant do much now). But your solution also looks neat and while handling with large datasets, I feel your solution will need less CPU cycles as you are not doing any conversions

Comment: Never mind.:) But keep in mind that in case you have one more entry for `selected_env` in `server_list`, the other answer does not find that one out.

Comment: aah! you mean mydev3 in server_list[] ?

Comment: I was talking about the case if you have another mydev2 in the list though it's unlikely.

Comment: And did you observe, that your output is giving sublist.

Comment: Yes, one sublist because there is only one mydev2. Each mydev2 in the list will be entered as sublists in the new list.

Answer (score 0):

One other option could be changing the for loop this way:

```
for item in range(len(server_list)):
   host_list = [item[selected_env] for item in server_list if selected_env in item]
host_list = list(itertools.chain(*host_list))
```